# Filter query on matching with another table

Tags: mysql

I have one table, with subscribers, who have two fields: country and language.
Another table has two columns only, country and language.
I need to filter subscribers, where I exclude those, whose combination of country and language matches the one in the mapping table.

I have

```
SELECT * from Subscribers 
LEFT JOIN Mapping on Mapping.Country != Subscribers.Country 
AND Mapping.Language != Subscribers.Language
```

However, it doesn't seem to filter at all. Is LEFT JOIN even the right direction to go?

Comment: Before you fix your data model, you should not “go” in any direction ... Why the redundancy, why do the subscribers have country and language - instead of just the _id_ of the corresponding record out of the second table …?

Answer (score 0):

use inner join:-

```
SELECT * from Subscribers 
inner join Mapping on Mapping.Country != Subscribers.Country 
AND Mapping.Language != Subscribers.Language
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try a different approach, something like this :

```
SELECT * from Subscribers 
LEFT JOIN Mapping on Mapping.Country = Subscribers.Country 
AND Mapping.Language = Subscribers.Language    
WHERE Mapping.Country IS NULL
```

What I'm doing is joining the tables on the match that we do NOT want, and using the "Where" clause to exclude those unwanted matches.

Hope something like this helps!